# background-image / background-size without a px based width

Tags: html, css

i have always the problem that if taking a background-image i am not able to see this image until i give the containing give a fixed width:

```
<div class="picture">
</div>

.picture {
background-image: url('img/start_bigpic.jpg');
background-size: 100%;
}
```

This does not work. Even if i update it likes this the image is not shown.

```
.picture {
background-image: url('img/start_bigpic.jpg');
background-size: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Only if i add a pixel-based width and height the image is shown properly, but i want only percentage based values in my fluid grid.

What is the solution for this? Can i show a background-image without having a pixel based width and height of the containing div?

Thanks!

**EDIT: Here is my jsfiddle of my problem. I can't get the picture gets displayed unless i use a px based height:** http://jsfiddle.net/t3YZt/

Comment: Percentages work only in relation to something else.. if the container of the `div` has height specified then the div will work..

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some height to a container, for instance body:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.picture {
    background-image:url(http://s23.postimg.org/kewe6boez/test_background_image.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m4YLb/)

Comment: Hey, i tried it but it is not working. The picture is not getting displayed: http://jsfiddle.net/t3YZt/

Answer (score 1):

To be sure your background container has any width, you should care of that by your own (setting its height to 100% (of its parent) or any other fixed height, or any auto height dependeintly on children inside).

Then, you do the following for the background:

```
.picture{
    background-size:cover; /* this way */
    background-size:content; /* or this one */
}
```

... to stretch the image accordingly to its container size.